# monitoring relationship between tables in a database

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, xampp

**Hi frnds plz tell me how to find the relations between tables in a mysql database.**

I am having nearly 271 tables in my database.I am using Xampp server and php 5

Please tell me...

Comment: Did you try this software? http://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/

Answer (score 1):

You will get it like this:

```
SHOW KEYS FROM tableName;
```

It will show the below information about the table:
**Table**
The name of the table.

**Non_unique**
0 if the index cannot contain duplicates, 1 if it can.

**Key_name**
The name of the index. If the index is the primary key, the name is always PRIMARY.

**Seq_in_index**
The column sequence number in the index, starting with 1.

**Column_name**
The column name.

**Collation**
How the column is sorted in the index. In MySQL, this can have values “A” (Ascending) or NULL (Not sorted).

**Cardinality**
An estimate of the number of unique values in the index. This is updated by running ANALYZE TABLE or myisamchk -a. Cardinality is counted based on statistics stored as integers, so the value is not necessarily exact even for small tables. The higher the cardinality, the greater the chance that MySQL uses the index when doing joins.

**Sub_part**
The number of indexed characters if the column is only partly indexed, NULL if the entire column is indexed.

**Packed**
Indicates how the key is packed. NULL if it is not.

**Null**
Contains YES if the column may contain NULL values and '' if not.

**Index_type**
The index method used (BTREE, FULLTEXT, HASH, RTREE).

**Comment**
Information about the index not described in its own column, such as disabled if the index is disabled

For More information : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/show-index.html